# sudo: don't ask password when logged in with ssh key

Tags: ssh, sudo

I'd like to setup `sudo` in such a way that it doesn't prompt me for a password when I authenticate to `sshd` with a key; but do otherwise.

I don't want an answer of "it doesn't work like that" because obviously that's the reason why I asked the question in the first place. I don't want the suggestion of creating two users for this.

Consider that for my personal servers I use Fedora, maybe there might be a hack with a temporal SELinux role based on authentication method, which can be then used in the sudoers file?

Comment: The problem is that `sudo` works at the user or group level. No matter how you worked out the mechanism of authentication, it still does not change the fact that the `NOPASSWD` option can only be applied at the group or user level. And either that user does have or does not have `NOPASSWD` for the commands specified in the `sudoers` file. The only solution _is_ to have a separate user, OR may be to edit the sudoers source to your needs and compile your own custom binary.

Comment: I asked a very similar question and got a good answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/520098/sudo-authentication-when-using-ssh-key-auth-with-keepassputty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a paper that describes a possible implementation on BSD: https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/lisa08/tech/full_papers/burnside/burnside_html/

It requires agent forwarding though, which I consider rather dangerous. Also, the site doesn't seem to link any sources or patches, and I don't think these changes have been implemented upstream.

It may also be possible to write a custom sudo auth plugin: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/sudo/sudo-3/sudo/auth/API

Seems rather complicated to me though, and I don't know if it's even possible to query sshd whether public key authentication has been used.

If I were you I would just put my public key into `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` and be done with it.

Comment: +1 for root's authorized_keys.  ssh in as root for admin tasks, and as a normal user otherwise.  Make sure that `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has `PermitRootLogin=without-password` (to allow root logins with an authorised key only) or `PermitRootLogin=yes` if you want to allow root to login with a password or a key (less secure)

Comment: While your answer is straight to the point. I find it off putting when the context of usage is something like; I log often from others people terminal to show something I've done on my server and let them roam it, and that's why I have sudo setup  to ask for a password every time. However that is an annoyance when I use it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Well, if you want to be safe, don't let other people use your account. I consider having shell access to be almost equivalent to having root access - once your attacker has a shell, a root exploit is all that's needed. Someone could alias your sudo command, and then you've already lost.